# How to specify EF byte[] in code first longer than 8000 bytes?

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, varbinarymax

I am using EF 6.1.3. Using code first sets a `byte[]` property in an entity to max. 8000 bytes. Any attempt to make it greater, that is MAX, fails.

`HasMaxLength(null)` (yes, the parameter is int?) still sets it to 8000,  `HasMaxLength(int.MaxValue)` or any other value greater than 8000 makes EF throw `System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException`:

> Schema specified is not valid. Errors:  (0,0) : error 0026: MaxLength
> '2147483647' is not valid. Length must be between '1' and '8000' for
> 'varbinary' type.

SQL server 13.0.2151 (mssqllocaldb) allows for varbinary(max):

[image]

This limit seems too severe to me. Trying to find a reason why it is imposed does not yield a good reason for this too. So, my question is

**How a byte[] can be mapped to varbinary(max) in EF code first?**

**PS:** The property is also 'required', but I am not sure if an optional property may be set to varbinary(MAX) either. Anyway, i have not tested this case since it does not make much sense to me.

Comment: If the property shouldn't have a max length, the obvious suggestion would be to not call `HasMaxLength`, but I suspect this isn't going to make a difference. You may want to check it, and if it indeed doesn't work, include that in your question.

Comment: So, are you suggesting to leave length unspecified and expect storing 8001 bytes to work? Does not make sense to me.

Comment: Eh? Not saying that the column has a max length, and then expecting the column not to have a max length, would make sense to me. You're not specifying the length. You're specifying the max length, which you don't want.

Answer (score 4):

Despite the multiple articles that states the solution is to add the following attribute

[Column(TypeName="image")]
byte[] Photo { get; set; }

I found the correct approach to be, adding instead this attribute

[MaxLength]
public byte[] Photo { get; set; }

With the Column(TypeName) recommendation I'll end up getting the following error with SQLCE:

The field Photo must be a string or array type with a maximum length of '4000'

Answer (score 2):

Well, I found a workaround to this. Specifying `HasColumnType("image")` solves the problem, but I still think that EF must allow for specifying `varbinary(max)` as well.

Moreover, *not all binary files are images*. ;)

And still part of the question remains unanswered, so I will put it this way:

**Why a byte[] property cannot be mapped to varbinary(max) in EF code first?**

Any comments (or answers of course) are welcome. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT (as per comment by Gert):** leaving the property without any specs makes EF generate `varbinary(max)`. Surprisingly simple!

Comment: I'm surprised. I can't repro your issue. If I have a property like `public byte[] Image { get; set; }` and let EF create the database without *any* further instruction, it just creates a `[varbinary](max)` column. If I use `HasColumnType("image")`, Sql server creates an `Image` column, but you shouldn't want that, because it's a deprecated data type.

Comment: Hm, you are right! Saying nothing to EF makes it generate varbinary(max). This is the KISS principle in action. Thanks Gert!

Comment: hvd also told you so in your OP's comments. ;-)

Comment: In my case, if I simply declare byte[] property it generates varbinary(4000). Maybe it's because my project uses SqlCE

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.
Fluent API

```
.IsMaxLength()
```

Answer (score -1):

Before you want to update the database take a look in the ***filename*** which is generated after you use "add-migration ***filename***" 
If you see a method "CreateTable" and see that a field which should te be a binary type with a lenght of MAX, it can be generated as c.Binary(maxLength: 8000), remove the parameter maxLength at all and then use update-database and after that you can check the created table in the SQL server database!

Comment: Do not thing this is a good idea. Migrations are auto-generated and manual "edits" are easily lost.

Comment: In fact, EF will try to stick to conventions and those changes will be lost on the next migration.